# Google Sheets pivot - remove empty rows

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a transaction table and I need to show open balances for it.

[image: Transactions]

[image: Pivot]

I didn't find how to hide empty rows. I want to show just GREEN rows. I tried to use filter but it doesn't work

[Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FFJXhg4E5alax56QdjkMUy9CxlWKgzA8iDAxjzmx948/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 Sorry, could you check access now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(""&QUERY(A1:D, 
 "select A,B,sum(D) where A is not null group by A,B pivot C"), 
 "^0$", ), 
 "where Col3 is not null or Col4 is not null");
 {"Grand Total", "", INDEX(QUERY(A1:D, 
 "select sum(D) where A is not null pivot C"), 2)}})
```

[image]

Comment: It is not OK - check Supp3 - Inv3 - Adv - it should be 0, but your filter excludes anount -100

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but I was able to do this in my pivot table, here is what I did:

- click on my primary field which is a date field.
- click add Filters.
- you will see blank, 123 and a couple of others that are already checked, uncheck blank and save.
  No more blank records.